TypeError: process_file() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given in Airflow DAG
I'm working on a Airflow DAG where I want to process a list of files sequentially but allow multiple files to be processed in parallel. I created the following DAG, but I encounter a TypeError when running it:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def fetch_files():
    return [f"file{i}" for i in range(1, 10)]

def extract_content(file):
    print(f"Extracting content from {file}")
    return f"content_of_{file}"

def transform_content(content):
    print(f"Transforming content: {content}")
    return f"transformed_{content}"

def generate_embeddings(content):
    print(f"Generating embeddings for {content}")
    return f"embeddings_for_{content}"

def load_into_db(embedding):
    print(f"Loading {embedding} into the database")
    pass

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='fetch_and_process',
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    fetch_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='fetch_files',
        python_callable=fetch_files
    )

    def process_file(file):
        with TaskGroup(group_id=f'process_{file}') as group:
            extract_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id="extract",
                python_callable=extract_content,
                op_args=[file]
            )

            transform_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id="transform",
                python_callable=transform_content,
                op_args=[extract_task.output]
            )

            embeddings_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id="generate_embeddings",
                python_callable=generate_embeddings,
                op_args=[transform_task.output]
            )

            load_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id="load",
                python_callable=load_into_db,
                op_args=[embeddings_task.output]
            )

            extract_task >> transform_task >> embeddings_task >> load_task

        return group

    process_tasks = PythonOperator.partial(
        task_id="process_file",
        python_callable=process_file
    ).expand(op_args=fetch_task.output)

    fetch_task >> process_tasks

What changes should I make to ensure that only one file at a time is passed to the process_file group task?
TypeError: process_file() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given

